# Converting lower case from file to upper case to another file

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I'm a student currently learning mips and I have a a question as followes:

Take all the lower-case letters from a file, convert them into upper-case letters and print them in a different file.
I tried opening the first file, called "Alice", this is the file i need to go through it and "taking" all the lower-case letters, convert them to upper-case and write them into another file called "AliceU", so in my code i opened the 2 files, read the first one and im trying to write to the other one but i think something isnt right, so im asking for practical information you might notice in my code that isnt correct

```
.data
filename: .asciiz "Allice.txt"
filename2: .asciiz "AlliceU.txt"
input: .space 1024

.text
# Open (for reading)
  li   $v0, 13              # system call for open file
  la   $a0, filename        # output file name
  li   $a1, 0               # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
  move $s0, $v0             # save the file descriptor 
  syscall                   # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)

ReadFile:
li   $v0, 14        # system call for reading from file
move $a0, $s0       # file descriptor 
la   $a1, input    # address of buffer from which to read
li   $a2, 1024       # hardcoded buffer length
syscall             # read from file

# Open (for writing)
  li   $v0, 13              # system call for open file
  la   $a0, filename2       # output file name
  li   $a1, 1               # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
  move $s1, $v0             # save the file descriptor 
  syscall                   # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)


Replace:
    lb $t1, input($t3)
    beq $t1, 0, exit
    blt $t1, 'a', case
    bgt $t1, 'z', case
    sub $t1, $t1, 32
    sb $t1, input($t3)

case: 
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    j Replace

WriteFile:
# Write to file
li $v0,15
move $a0,$s1
la $a1,input
la $a2,1024
syscall

exit:
# Close the file 
  li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
  move $a0, $s1      # file descriptor to close
  syscall            # close file
  li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
  move $a0, $s0      # file descriptor to close
  syscall            # close file
```

So I took some advices from question asked here before but I couldn't understand deeply how this thing works exactly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hey there! Sorry for the bad post this is my first one and it took me some time to figure out how to create the code block,
I tried opening the first file, called  "Alice", this is the file i need to go through it and "taking" all the lower-case letters, convert them to upper-case and write them into another file called "AliceU", so in my code i opened the 2 files, read the first one and im trying to write to the other one but i think something isnt right, so im asking for practical information you might notice in my code that isnt correct

Comment: It's all good, the markdown used by Stack Overflow can take a little while to get down pat.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just noticed that you had edited your last comment. It's been a few years since I've done anything with MIPS. The last project I had was multiplying two 32 bit floats and storing the 64 bit product in two 32 bit registers. We never got to file IO but it shouldn't be too difficult. Let me look over your code and I'll get back to you.